# Android. Переход между фрагментами

Tags: android, android-fragment

Подскажите как сделать переход из одного фрагмента в другой по нажатию кнопки?

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

FragmentGlavnaya fglavnaya;
FragmentMusey fMusey;
FragmentVistavki fvistavki;
FragmentMus fmus;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    fglavnaya = new FragmentGlavnaya();
    fMusey = new FragmentMusey();
    fvistavki = new FragmentVistavki();
    fmus = new FragmentMus();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    android.app.FragmentTransaction ftrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if (id == R.id.nav_glavnaya) {
        ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fglavnaya);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_musey) {
        ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fMusey);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_vistavki) {
        ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fvistavki);

    }ftrans.commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

**Fragment Musey:**

```
public class FragmentMusey extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public FragmentMusey() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


public static FragmentVistavki newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FragmentVistavki fragment = new FragmentVistavki();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_musey2, container, false);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}


public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема?

Answer (score 2):

На данный момент у вас транзакций по фрагментам управляются через Navigation Drawer,получается  у вас в данном случае управляет фрагментами активити. Как я понел вы хотите , вы хотите непосредственно менять их через кнопку во фрагментах.

Самый простой способ : создать метод  у активити  onNavigationItemSelected:

```
public void onNavigationItemSelected2(Int  item) {

android.app.FragmentTransaction ftrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

if (item == 1) {
    ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fglavnaya);

} else if (item == 2) {
    ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fMusey);

} else if (item == 3) {
    ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fvistavki);

}ftrans.commit();
```

}

И вызывать из фрагмента передавая item:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).onNavigationItemSelected2(1);
```